# Fastest communication between Arduino and PC

Tags: serial, arduino-due, array

I am using an Arduino 2 which collects data from a set of microphones and stores it in an array of unsigned short of 40000 elements and sends them to the PC via Serial USB.

It is working but I'd like to obtain more speed without any errors.

Can you suggest me the best way to do it? Even changing communication.

Thank you

Comment: Which USB serial are you using? The ATMega port or the native USB port?

Comment: And what baud rate, and what encoding?  How fast does it currently go, and how much faster do you want (well, need) to achieve?

Comment: I am using the programming port.

Comment: 115200 Baudrate, I would like to obtain the best performances for a semi-real time application. I am currently using Serial.println(value1, value2, value3, ...,value8)\n.  In PC parsing of the datas I sometimes get errors because it sends two different row in the same. Thank you

Comment: So, again, how fast does it currently go, and how fast do you need it to go?  At 115kbps, you could in principle, suitably encoded, send 40k 16bit values in about 5.5 seconds.  How long is it taking in your implementation, and how long do you want it to take? Everyone wants the best performance (and the least effort and the lowest cost and the highest reliability). Give us a clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to using SerialUSB instead and use the other USB port. The baud rate is meaningless then - it runs at the speed of the USB port, which is a lot faster than serial (Linux reports it as 480Mbps, though I can't see an 84MHz chip doing that...).

```
void setup() {
    SerialUSB.begin(115200); // The number is irrelevant but it needs something in there
}

void loop() {
    SerialUSB.println(millis());
    delay(100);
}
```

For greater throughput you could devise some packet-based binary protocol to optimize your data flow to use less bytes.

Comment: seems legit.  How to do it?

Comment: `SerialUSB.begin(115200); SerialUSB.println("Whatever")`. And plug into the other socket of course.

Comment: Why the delay? Is to avoid errors or just to simulate stuff?

Comment: That is just a simple example so you can see the port working. The delay has no purpose other than to allow your eyes to register what they are seeing before it is gone.

Answer (score 1):

SPI: technically no upper limit so long as both parties can keep up and the wires are good enough. Mbps easily doable.

Comment: I am already using SPI for communication between Arduino and an ADC shield. Can I use it anyway and how?

Comment: spi targeting is controlled by the _CS pin(s). Multiple spi devices can hang off the same bus - assuming your shield is properly designed.